# Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, express

I have nodejs repl and I am using SQLite. Somehow the SQList database file is giving me below error.

```
events.js:165
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
Emitted 'error' event at:
```

Here is the [REPL](https://repl.it/@zafar_saleem/DarkgrayConcernedWifi).